# Initialize props from Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to find the best way to initialize my component props...

I have a component that is getting its values from the store. The props are usually fed with mapStateToProps which is fine for most of the cases.

However, as mapStateToProps is only called when the store is updated then when I load my component without any store update performed my component is not initialized with the props from the store.

I read things about setting "ownprops" as the 2nd argument of mapStateToProps so that it will be invoked when the props from a parent component are updated but I don't think it is a right option.

There must be a simple way and it must be because I am a beginner that I don't see how to handle what seems to be a common topic.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: For initial render it should trigger mapStateToProps. Could you provide a link to the sandbox with your real use case (e.g. via jsbin)?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial state of your reducer, which may be what you're looking for.

```
function myReducer(state = { /* your initial state here */, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    /* action handlers go here */
  default: return state;
  }
}
```

[Here's some additional information on setting up default values in reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are rendering a component that relies on data from the store but that the store is empty when the component is rendered.

You need to update the store before the component is rendered. That's the easiest answer.

So, say you have a parent component that renders a child component that is connected to the store. That parent component should update the store before the child component is rendered.

Or if that hierarchy isn't the case then you could dispatch an action in the componentWillMount() life cycle method.

Another option would be to place default values in the reducer.

It's hard to know the correct solution without seeing your code/use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will see what is the best for my case. I am still wondering what kind of action do I need to dispatch to make the mapStateToProps look for the store content. Would it be a kind of a fake action creator with no values ?